# Consecutive Integers Pythagorean Triplets

Tags: pythagorean-triples

I have a question for which I was not able to find an answer online. I was wondering how many Pythagorean Triplets we have found till now which consists of three consecutive integers like $(3,4,5)$.

Comment: There are no more. Try solving $x^2 + (x+1)^2 = (x+2)^2$.

Comment: [Similar but different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3788477/arithmetic-progression-a-b-c-with-a2b2-c2-and-gcda-b-c-1)

Comment: @player3236 There are two solutions to the equation you showed in your comment. These are $(-1,0,1)$ and $(3,4,5)$ as I showed in my answer below. Granted one is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2 +(x+1)^2=(x+2)^2\\\implies x^2 +(x+1)^2-(x+2)^2=0\\\implies x^2 - 2 x - 3 = 0$$

Using the quadratic equation, we find
$$x\in\{3,-1\}\implies \text{the set of triples}\quad S=\{(3,4,5),(-1,0,1)\}$$
There are no other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For slightly simpler numbers, let $x$ be the middle number then you have to solve
$$
\begin{split}
(x-1)^2 + x^2 &= (x+1)^2 \\
x^2 &= (x+1)^2 - (x-1)^2 = 2x\cdot2
\end{split}
$$
which yields $x=0$ and $x=4$. Can you finish?